# UIDatePicker doesn't change value

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

I have `UIViewController` with `UIDatePicker` inside. I connect `UIDatePicker` with `IBOutlet` property in header class, because I'm using storyboards in my app:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol CreationDateDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
    -(void)selectedDateIs:(NSString*)dateValue;
@end

@interface SelectCreationDateViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
}
@property (nonatomic,assign)id<CreationDateDelegate>creationDateDelegate;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;

@end
```

--- .m -----

```
#import "SelectCreationDateViewController.h"
@interface SelectCreationDateViewController ()
{
    NSString *dateFromString;
}
@end

@implementation SelectCreationDateViewController
@synthesize creationDateDelegate,datePicker;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) 
    {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
    self.title = @"Select creation date";
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [datePicker setHidden:NO];
    datePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    [datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];

    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(changeValueOfDatePicker:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    NSString *dateFromString = [formatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
    [self.creationDateDelegate selectedDateIs:dateFromString];
}

-(void)changeValueOfDatePicker:(id)sender{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    dateFromString = [formatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
    [self.creationDateDelegate selectedDateIs:dateFromString];
    NSLog(@"Date from string value equal %@",dateFromString);
}
@end
```

Why every time when I change the value of the DatePicker returned value does not change? Any ideas? Also, let me know if I am making any mistake in the code.

Comment: Where is your code of changeValueOfDatePicker: method?

Comment: where is declared delegates of UIDatePicker

Comment: @iDev  There is no delegate for UIDatePicker.

Comment: what is get from NSLog

Comment: befor check value is there in datePicker.date by NSlog

Comment: @sonodamiano set some dateFormate to dateFormatter and see the result. See my answer.

Comment: [NSDate date], on every changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set some dateformate also

```
 -(void)changeValueOfDatePicker:(id)sender{

        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];

        dateFromString = [formatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
        [self.creationDateDelegate selectedDateIs:dateFromString];
        NSLog(@"Date from string value equal %@",dateFromString);
    }
```

Comment: [formatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date]; By defualt there is no datFormate set to NSDateFormatter. You manually need to set some dateFromat, then only dateFormatter is able to perform associated opration. Better read this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

**Fix it by adding this line of code**,

only if you are using iOS7
- in method (void)viewDidLoad method

```
[self.datePicker setDate:[NSDate date] animated:YES];
```